# Did the Romans really use the binomial formula to calculate products?

Tags: math-history

I'm not quite sure if this is the right place to ask this question, but I figure someone might have heard about the following, which I was told as a motivating story in an undergraduate intro to algorithms class years back. Unfortunately, I have no means of obtaining a source on this account:

In Roman times, when going to the market, it would be a commonplace problem to multiply e.g. a price with a quantity of an item to calculate the total price. Since people weren't able to do grade-school multiplication, let alone in their heads, this posed a serious problem. One solution would have been to produce boards that showed a multiplication table. But the quadratic space (weight, production time, etc.) requirements made this not viable.

However, Romans could do addition, subtraction (using some aids, possibly), and division by two, relatively easily; at least compared to outright multiplication of arbitrary numbers.
So the clever solution the Romans came up with was to produce boards (of linear size in the size of the range of numbers to be captured) that contained a list of *squares*. Then, they could employ $ab = ((a+b)^2 - a^2 - b^2)/2$ to perform multiplication, reading off the squares from their table and adding/subtracting as they knew how to do it.

Is this something the instructor made up, or has anyone ever heard of this practice? If so, I would be extremely happy about a source for this.

Comment: Maybe you can also ask here: https://hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: I second b00n heT's comment re: asking on the [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) SE site instead. In fact, when I saw your question, I was about to make the same recommendation myself. Nonetheless, before possibly posting there, I also recommend you first check their [Help Center](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/help) for what's on, and not on, topic. Also, try to determine what tag(s) to use, including checking for duplicates. For example, searching with the [roman-empire](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roman-empire) tag, there's ...

Comment: (cont.) several related questions, e.g., [How could the Roman Empire manage their accounting without a proper number system?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/11639), [Were ancient Romans so bad at computations before Arab numerals?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/9791) and, in particular, [How did Romans do multiplications?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/7938). However, note I haven't actually personally checked any of these, but it's what I recommend you do yourself instead first before possibly using that site.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. For some reason I was not aware of the existence of these SEs.

Comment: The number system they had was very unlucky concerning multiplication. I guess they simply arranged the objects in a rectangular and counted them. Of course this way , they could manage only very easy multiplications , but I have no idea how they could have done better with such a number system.

Answer (score 3):

The same story exists with the Romans replaced by the Babylonians. There is not a single trace for either claim.

Both Babylonians and Romans used an abacus for doing calculations; in the case of the Romans, such instruments were found, for Babylonians investigations of calculation errors at least suggest the use of a primitive abacus.

Comment: Very interesting -- and too bad. I'll leave the question open for a bit and see if something else bubbles up. If not, I will accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, from my very amateurish understanding, for thousands of years the abacus (in various incarnations) was the way to do calculations, with various grouping methods. The _notation_ for numbers was (apparently?) not tightly bound to the calculational devices of the abacus. Just the/a way to write the final answer.